# Rails 4 Heroku assets:precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, nitrousio

I am trying to create a Rails app in Heroku. I run it locally(nitrous.io) and works fine. I am not sure what is going on here and no idea what I did wrong. I have already read many other answers on SO but none seemed to work for me. I hope someone has experience with this and can help me out!

Following the directions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline) I already added this:

```
#config/application.rb
config.serve_static_assets = true

#Gemfile
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

.

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline                                                                                                                               
   Running: rake assets:precompile                                                                                                                                      
   rake aborted!                                                                                                                                                        
   IndexError: string not matched                                                                                                                                       
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:76:in `[]='                
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:76:in `block in config'    
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:74:in `tap'                
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:74:in `config'             
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:69:in `resolve'            
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:46:in `configurations='                   
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:128:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'                                                                                                                 
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'        
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'         
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'     
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'                 
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'              
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:118:in `block in <class:Railtie>'      
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'                        
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'                                  
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'            
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'                     
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'                           
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'                               
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'                            
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'                                                                        
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'                
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'       
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'        
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'                
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:264:in `require_environment!'                  
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'             
   /tmp/build_5191aa8d-0f78-44fd-a9ad-b6620c655951/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in define'   
   Tasks: TOP => environment                                                                                                                                            
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)                                                                                   
   !     Precompiling assets failed.            

   !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IndexError: string not matched
```

Indicates that somewhere a string is being accessed as a Hash. For example

```
@name = 'John'
@name['b'] => will throw this error
```

Take a look at your config files, it seems to halt there.